# Spring Config Server for enterprise

Tags: spring-cloud

I am trying to setup an enterprise level Spring Config Server which will be used by multiple config client applications across the company.  As the `encrypt.key` should be common across multiple clients, is it possible to protect sensitive information of a client application from other client applications. Am I missing something? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is one way to set things up.  You can also let the config server handle decryption so the clients only get decrypted values and secure the connection from client to server using spring security.